# Package and run nodejs application in an offline server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, deployment, next.js, package

I'm currently using NextJS and to run a production build, I use `npm run build` followed by `npm run start`. This all works well on my local machine.

However, I need to deploy this app on an offline machine where I may not have an internet connection to install all the node packages.

I've taken a look at npm pkg and npm pack utilities, but not quite sure which is the best one to use in the context of a nextjs app.

Would appreciate any advice on the best way to do this.

Edit: thinking along the lines of how I would build my maven project and have a .jar output which I can use to deploy to any other machine as a single deployable file.

Comment: do you mean you want to compile it into an application? if so i recommend looking into ElectronJS.

Comment: Yes, ideally, something like building a maven project and having a .jar output which can be run as a standalone deployable on another machine. Thanks, I'll take a look at Electron.

Comment: No problem. If you're new to electron i would recommend watching some nextjs + electron videos or looking at a nextjs + electron template [like this](https://github.com/saltyshiomix/nextron).